# Why this icons of Elevated Buttons in a flutter web app has broken alignment in firebase deploy at mobile devices?

Tags: flutter

FIX: It seem like flutter js compiller doesn't accept ElevatedButton, i changed for a Container with GestureDetector and it worked all fine.

I'm making my professional portfolio, but today when i deployed my flutter web app in firebase hosting, this icons simply broke alignment in mobile.
**In production** they're all right, in desktop and dev tools mobile resize:
[How it has to be (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIWBg.png)

**CRUCIAL: When deployed**, in desktop and dev tools mobile they're good too, but when i open it in my **cellphone** the result is this:
[How it is (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO8LO.jpg)

Code of the component:

```
Row(
children: widget.btnsList.asMap().entries.map((e) {

return Container(
                      height: 26,
                      padding: e.key > 0
                          ? const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5)
                          : const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                      child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 10, vertical: 7),
                            backgroundColor:
                                Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 1, // thickness
                                    color: Colors.white // color
                                    ),
                                // border radius
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7))),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await launchUrl(Uri.parse(e.value["url"]));
                        },
                        icon: e.value["icon"],
                        label: Text(
                          e.value["text"],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ), // <-- Text
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
```

I'm passing to this widged a list in the constructor, witch has the icon and text of the button.

Anyone knows the fix?

I tried nothing until now, i don't enven know what to try.
Expect a way to align this icons in mobile

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post the solution as a self-answer - rather than as an edit on the question. That way the system also recognizes that your question has an answer, making it easier for others to benefit from your findings.